# "This method must only be called once" error using QNetworkReply

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++

I have this error coming when I try to press simple link in the same domain and in the same site. I'm using Qt 4.8 in Windows.

This is the error:

```
QNetworkReplyImplPrivate::error: Internal problem, this method must only be called once.
```

I keep seeing it in the Visual Studio console.

Comment: Please note that tags stand alone.  That is, combining `visual` and `studio` doesn't mean you're talking about MS Visual Studio.

Comment: Do you have an self-contained, minimal example?

Comment: im using the fancybrowser example in the webkit dir in examples in  Qt 4.8.2
the problem i can't give you the site url , but be sure its just alink  
to different page

Comment: How can a post be 6 yrs old, viewed 3K times, and not have an answer, be tagged as duplicate, ...?